# Multiple rounds of AES Encryption taking forever on Android

Tags: java, android, encryption

I'm trying to implement my own KeePass app for Android, mainly for learning purposes. I have found from http://blog.sharedmemory.fr/en/2014/04/30/keepass-file-format-explained/

> To generate the final master key, you first need to generate the transformed key :
>
> create an AES cipher, taking Transform Seed as its key/seed,
>
> initialize the transformed key value with the composite key value (transformed_key = composite_key),
>
> use this cipher to encrypt the transformed_key N times ( transformed_key = AES(transformed_key), N times),
>
> hash (with SHA-256) the transformed_key  (transformed_key = sha256(transformed_key) ),
>
> concatenate the Master Seed to the transformed_key (transformed_key = concat(Master Seed, transformed_key) ),
>
> hash (with SHA-256) the transformed_key to get the final master key (final_master_key = sha256(transformed_key) ).

I have step 2 implimented with:

```java
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
for (long i = 0; i < rounds; ++i) {
     data = c.doFinal(data);
}
```

However, it runs really really really slow. I know there has to be a faster way since other KeePass apps on Android don't run so slow when decrypting the database. When I watch it Android Device Monitor it sits is running the doFinal piece over and over, which makes sense, but there has to be a faster way.

Comment: What is `data`? That is supposed to be the composite key, and `data` seems like an odd name for it.

Comment: Yes, it starts as the composite key and turns into the transformed key before the hashing.

Comment: Currently you are generating a new `data` buffer each time. This is not necessary (e.g. using `ByteBuffer` instances that point to the same array). Also note that there may be a big difference between running on the simulator and an actual device.